# docker compose up not working on compose V2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've installed docker and docker compose v2 on wsl. Using `docker --version`, `docker compose version`, `docker-compose --version` I get:

```
Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu4
Docker Compose version v2.14.2
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
```

But when I run `docker compose up` I got the following error:

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

Why am I getting this error?

The tree view from my dir:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── data
├── docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: What's different from where you ran `docker compose version` vs `docker compose up`?

Comment: Nothing, I run in the same CLI `docker compose up` and `docker compose version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `docker-compose up` instead